# Computing the Minimum Volume Enclosing Ellipsoid using the Ellipsoid Method

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, conic-sections, ellipsoids

I need your expertise in solving the following the follow problem:

Given a convex body P, which is given implicitly by an oracle (either membership or separation), the objective is to find a minimum enclosing ellipsoid using the ellipsoid method.

To achieve such task, we need to formulate the problem such that our variable will represent the ellipsoid:

$$ \min f(x) \\ \text{subject to} \\  x \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2 + n}$$
where x will be something like "$\begin{bmatrix} G \\ c \end{bmatrix}$ " where $G$ is positive definite matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $C$ is a vector which represent a center of an ellipsoid.

What should be given to the ellipsoid method exactly so that it can achieve this purpose?!
(what are the constraints? Is $f(x) = \left| G\right|$?)

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you mentionning an existing method, or is it the theme of a project that has been given to you without much guidance ?

Comment: I am mentioning an existing method. which is basically using the ellipsoid method to compute the minimum volume enclosing ellipsoid?

Comment: If this is not possible, then what can be done to compute such ellipsoid when only an oracle is given to describe the convex body $P$?